# Compose draw text with border and gradient

Tags: text, android-jetpack-compose, draw

Is there any way to draw text like that in compose which will have border and shadow like drop. Font does not matter.

[image: Text to be drawn]

I have tried AnnotatedString to apply the same gradient to each letter with this code:

```
        val colorStops = arrayOf(
            0.0f to Color(0xffe2e145),
            0.2f to Color(0xff7ab624)
        )
            Text(
                text = buildAnnotatedString {
                    for (letter in "ANIMALS".toCharArray()) {
                        withStyle(
                            SpanStyle(
                                brush = Brush.linearGradient(colorStops = colorStops)
                            )
                        ) {
                            append(letter)
                        }
                    }
                },
                fontSize = 60.sp
            )
```

but it just gets parsed wrong and only gets applied to first letter only

[image: Text which is actually drawn]

Do you know what I could be doing wrong or is there a better way to do this?
One more thing would like text to be replacable.

If anyone has any ideas would be very grateful.

Edit

This is how stroke looks like on my Galaxy S10

[image: Incorrect stroke]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Box` to put more `Text` elements on top of another:

```
val colorStops = listOf(
    Color(0xffe2e145),
    Color(0xff7ab624)
)

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {

    //Filled Text
    Text(
        text = longText,
        color = Color(0xffe2e145),
        fontSize = 64.sp
    )

    //Shadow text with a gradient color.
    Text(
        text = longText,
        modifier = Modifier.offset(2.dp, 3.dp),
        style = TextStyle(
            brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                colors = colorStops,
                tileMode = TileMode.Mirror
            )
        ),
        fontSize = 64.sp
    )

    //Text with stroke border
    Text(
        text = longText,
        color = Color(0xffB71C1C),
        style = TextStyle.Default.copy(
            fontSize = 64.sp,
            drawStyle = Stroke(
                miter = 10f,
                width = 2f,
                join = StrokeJoin.Round
            )
        )
    )
 }
```

[image]

Another option is to apply a shadow and a brush to the `Text`:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {

    //Shadow and Brush Text
    Text(
        text = longText,
        style = TextStyle(
            shadow = Shadow(
                offset = Offset(8f, 8f),
                blurRadius = 6f,
                color = LightGray
            ),
            brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                colors = colorStops,
                tileMode = TileMode.Mirror
            )
        ),
        fontSize = 64.sp
    )

    //Text with stroke border
    Text(
        text = longText,
        color = Color(0xffB71C1C),
        style = TextStyle.Default.copy(
            fontSize = 64.sp,
            drawStyle = Stroke(
                miter = 10f,
                width = 2f,
                join = StrokeJoin.Round
            )
        )
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Gabriele. Your answer is working on an older phone but when I try it on my Galaxy s10 I get incorrect stroke for some reason any idea why that could be. Edited the answer to show it. Do you have any idea why that could be?

Comment: It seems like it's only an issue with my phone. So answer accepted. Thanks for your help.